# Invert a shape in illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator, vector

I have a rectangle object in Illustrator with a hole in it which forms the actual desired object. Can I invert the object so the inner hole becomes the actual object?

Comment: Menu Object > Compound Path > Release; Cmd + Alt + Shift + 8 – Mac; Ctrl + Alt + Shift + 8 – Win

Comment: @Danielillo That's an answer I'd upvote if it were in the answer space and I'd not given it myself just now ;)

Comment: @Vincent Yes, I have become a bit selective with the questions. I have the feeling this question has been asked a hundred times.

Comment: @Danielillo If you find a dupe, please vote to close this question as a dupe of that. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Select your current shape, using the selection tool (<kbd>V</kbd> or <kbd>Esc</kbd>);
2. Choose Object > Compound Path > Release (<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl/Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>8</kbd>).

This creates two paths: one being your rectangle, the other your desired shape.